# i am not able to find btn_default_pressed in android 4.1 Api

Tags: android

i am not able to find btn_default_pressed in android 4.1 Api.
Can anybody tell me where it situated in android API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it under Path to your Android SdK-->platforms-->android-16-->data-->res-->drawable-mdpi--> btn_default_pressed.9

[image]

Comment: Thanks K_Anas, can you please tell me in android API path -res-layout-log_text_box_1.xml. Hox the background color is cahnged on button click.and how background color of button takes more place than the size of button.

Comment: @user1395259 can you mark the answer as accepted, and ask your question in another thread and give me a link to it, because other users must know that this question is resolved!!

Comment: ok K_Anas. this is the link for my new question,plz let me know if you have any solution for this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323762/how-the-background-color-changes-on-button-click-in-android-api-4-1-in-android