# how the background color changes on button click in android api 4.1 in android?

Tags: android

I want to know that on button click how the background color changed here and it takes place more than the button size..Can anybody tell e that from where the background color is coming to this??
inside the android api 4.1, at path: **Android API-res-layout-log_text_box_1.xml** file looks like this.

```
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/log_text_box_1_add_text"/>

    <com.example.android.apis.text.LogTextBox
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:background="@drawable/box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/log_text_box_1_do_nothing_text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry but i can't understand what you want from where did you have copied this layout?

Comment: are you looking for @drawable/box?

Comment: Android API-res-layout-log_text_box_1.xml.

Comment: Android API-res-layout-log_text_box_1.xml. I copied it from here.and for more fesibility, run the android API Demo from android sdk then go to Text-LogTextBox. After this the new activity will open with the two button 1st is ADD and another is Do Nothing. When you click on any button then see the background color is changing of that button,but the change color takes more space than the button. WHY AND HOW THIS IS HAPPENNING?? This is exactly my question. Kindly reply if you are aware with this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is the default android style button for the Holo theme, the selector use for such buttons are located in *Path to your sdk \platforms\android-16\data\res\drawable* with names such as : `btn_default_holo_dark.xml` and `btn_default_holo_light.xml`

the drawable used for the first selector are :

```
btn_default_normal_holo_dark.9
```

[image]

```
btn_default_disabled_holo_dark.9
```

[image]

```
btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_dark.9
```

[image]

```
btn_default_focused_holo_dark.9
```

[image]

```
btn_default_pressed_holo_dark.9
```

[image]

The last 9-patch image is the one responsible for the effect of exceeding the button's borders, hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.I will check it out. Tanks a lot

Comment: @user1395259 the drawable are in  path to android sdk \platforms\android-16\data\res\drawable-mdpi, you are welcome!!